# Sending mail using Mailjet smtp in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailjet

I need to send a few mails with my laravel application, and they are not really personalized. I've used the markdown mail system in laravel, and everything was smooth for the tests. I had mailtrap setup to catch all the mails, no problems.

Now I have to use mailjet to send mails - not to create emails and everything, just to have an adress to send them and a way to know where they did go. I've installed [the laravel-mailjet package](https://github.com/mailjet/laravel-mailjet), I've done everything in the doc (except the last part, my mails already work), but no luck, nothing works. I don't have any error in the logs, I don't have any error when the mail is supposed to be thrown, it just kinda don't try to send the mail at all. I've tried on local and prod (I was thinking that maybe it was because of the dns), everything is perfectly setup between my dns and mailjet, but I can't launch any mail and google is no help on this one.

.env

```
    MAIL_MAILER=mailjet
    MAIL_HOST=in-v3.mailjet.com
    MAIL_PORT=587
    MAIL_USERNAME={api key}
    MAIL_PASSWORD={api secret}
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
    MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS={mail}
    MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
    MAILJET_APIKEY={api key}
    MAILJET_APISECRET={api secret}
```

app.php

```php
    'providers' => [
        ...
        Mailjet\LaravelMailjet\MailjetServiceProvider::class,
        Mailjet\LaravelMailjet\MailjetMailServiceProvider::class,
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        ...
        'Mailjet' => Mailjet\LaravelMailjet\Facades\Mailjet::class,
    ],
```

mail.php

```php
    'mailers' => [
        ....
        'mailjet' => [
            'transport' => 'mailjet',
        ],
    ],
```

services.php

```php
'mailjet' => [
        'key' => env('MAILJET_APIKEY'),
        'secret' => env('MAILJET_APISECRET'),
        'transactional' => [
            'call' => true,
            'options' => [
                'url' => 'api.mailjet.com',
                'version' => 'v3.1',
                'call' => true,
                'secured' => true
            ]
        ],
        'common' => [
            'call' => true,
            'options' => [
                'url' => 'api.mailjet.com',
                'version' => 'v3',
                'call' => true,
                'secured' => true
            ]
        ],
        'v4' => [
            'call' => true,
            'options' => [
                'url' => 'api.mailjet.com',
                'version' => 'v4',
                'call' => true,
                'secured' => true
            ]
        ],
    ]
```

I've tried to erase all my modifications and just let the .env, with no luck too. What am I missing?

Comment: Mention the error that you are getting.

Comment: @KaushikThakkar There is no error. No log, no error 500, nothing, nada. The mail just doesn't go.

Comment: Add code here, you have written to send mail or call mailjet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found my problem. The whole setup was good, it was in the Mailable class that I was missing something; the mail used to send the confirmation wasn't register in Mailjet. Just a modification in the `->from(email)` in the class and everything works now.

It's just weird that I couldn't get any error message that could give me clue on what was going on, no error in logs and no error on Mailjet.

Comment: Do you know how to get the MailJet response, so that I can get the `MessageID` in order to get the status of the email, especially to know whether it could be delivered or not?